# Requiring authorization in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

The following code in ConfigureServices() method in Startup.cs was working fine in my ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1 project. Now, I'm migrating it to the final version but this line is giving me an error that says "AuthorizationPolicyBuilder does not contain a constructor that takes that many arguments".

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
   // Require authenticated users throughout the application
   options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build()));
   );
```

What modifications do I need to make to this line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually just a syntax error. Take away the semi-colon:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
    // Require authenticated users throughout the application
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build()))
);
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed this and another issue. I had switched to services.AddMvcCore(options =>... which then created other issues. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690643/iauthorizationservice-in-asp-net-core-app?noredirect=1#comment64760849_38690643 Once I fixed this, I could remove the AddAuthoriztion. Thanks.